# Android Browser Back Arrow/Resubmit Submitting Old Dynamic Form Data

Tags: jquery, android, forms, browser, mobile

I have created a system which dynamically builds a form and populates it with hidden inputs and then submits it.  I use jQuery to do this and have used:

`$('big form string here').appendTo('body').submit();`

and various other forms of adding it to the DOM and submitting.

The system is implemented within the jQuery Mobile framework.

I have set the system to NOT use ajax for any page changes or form submissions.  I have also manually specified data-ajax='false' for each form and on each page.

In addition, the page headers contain this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"/> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" />
```

The problem I am having seems to be only on the Android Browser and involves **submitting the form the second time** after hitting the browser's **back arrow**.

Upon returning back to the page with the previously dynamically created form, I check for forms and any inputs in the entire DOM and find none.  Which is accurate considering the above header values right?  On submit, I dynamically recreate the form again just like the first time.

But... **When I then look at the form and the data before submission, it still has the previous submission data in it, and it submits the previous data back to the server!**

This does not happen in Mobile Safari, Firefox, or Chrome.

The only way I was able to get it working was to hard code the form in the HTML on the page which would require a significant refactoring of my project!

I am not sure if I'm dealing with a hidden DOM object here, or something to do with the browser history object or the some jQuery Mobile caching or something else.  Since it's on the Android phone, it's not easy to look at the whole DOM.

Nothing seems to have tamed this beast.

If anybody is interested in actually seeing this form in action and maybe has some powerful ways of debugging it on Android, please request it and I can send you a link and instructions.

Also please let me know the most efficient way of emulating Android in some sort of debug mode.

Thanks much.